# Display combobox field in label

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a combobox which reads a directory and displays the file names in the combobox.  What I'm trying to do is when a value is selected in the combobox I wish to display this in a label.

I have tried the following

```
    Label1.Text = Combobox1.SelectedValue
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

My coding to display value in the combobox

```
With Combobox1
     .DisplayMember = "Name" 
     .ValueMember = "FullName"
     .DataSource = New IO.DirectoryInfo("Path").GetFiles().Select( _ 
       Function(fi) New With {.Name = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension( _ 
       fi.FullName), fi.FullName}).ToArray()
End With
```

I have the first snippet of coding in the Combobox1_SelectedIndexChanged event.

The "FullName" works with textbox1 when i select a value in the combobox but I want to display the "Name" in label1.text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :

```
ComboBox1.SelectedItem.Name
```

or

```
ComboBox1.SelectedItem.FullName
```

Depending on what you are trying to do.

`SelectedItem` is an anonymous object, so the names of the properties will be different if you use this on a different Combobox that has a different Key/Value.

Answer (score 2):

Use `SelectedItem.ToString()`. `SelectedValue` is the value assigned to an item that the user doesn't see. It's kinda like a tag, if you want to look at it that way. If you don't explicitly set the value for an item, it will be NULL, so that's why you see nothing in your label.

`SelectedValue` is real useful for data-binding. For example, you will want the user to see the name "John Smith", but you want to set the value to the primary key of your database row it's bound to. If you update the database based on that item, you can pass the `SelectedValue` as the parameter (the PK for that John Smith's row) since it's already set.

Comment: I wrote this answer before you massively edited your question, so it may no longer apply. Now it looks like you're asking why SelectedValue isn't what you want it to be, not why nothing's being displayed in your label.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow like this. Hope this helps.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text=comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(); 

                    OR
    label1.Text=comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();

}
```

Comment: SelectedItem and SelectedValue aren't the same thing. They can be set to the same value, sure, but that's they're not equal.

Comment: Sorry but even with Label1.Text = Combobox1.SelectedValue.ToString it displays the same as the textbox, I only want to display in the label what is displayed in the combobox.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works for me, just give the column name you want to access text from in this code.

```
label1.Text = specific.Rows[comboBox1.SelectedIndex]["Column name"].ToString();
```